# Gradle: war task overrides test tasks in subprojects

Tags: testing, gradle, war, multi-project

I have "test" tasks in subprojects:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

test {
  description = 'Runs tests that are marked as @FastTest.'

  useJUnit {  includeCategories 'category.FastTest'  }
}
```

If I add "war" task to the root project:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
```

, it overrides test tasks in subprojects, e.g. it ignores my "test" task properties.
How do I suppress "war" task overriding "test" tasks?

Comment: Applying the 'war' plugin to the root project won't have any effect on the subprojects. If you want tests in the subprojects you will need to apply 'war', 'java' or 'groovy' etc plugin to the subprojects

Comment: I have "apply plugin: 'java'" in subprojects.